# Converting the DOM element in a String

Tags: html, dom, svg

I am working on svg. I made some shapes in svg using my javascript code. Now what i have to do is to get that code of svg which has been made as i draw some thing. i want to get that code in a form of string so for the sake of reuse or if can put that code in a .svg file it outputs the same what i made by myself using my javascript code.
Like My code made this

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="500" height="500" id="one">
<g id="container">
    <rect id ="rect" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="pink"
          stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />

</g>
```

Now what should i do to get all the code from  to  in a form of string and i can print that.

Answer (score 1):

To get the equivalent of `innerHTML` in SVG you must first serialize the SVG, it is done like this:

```
​var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var string = serializer.serializeToString(svg);​
```

You can see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrPwS/

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your javascript:

function getMyString()  {    
  var theStringIWant = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
  d.getElementbyId('theBox').value = theStringIWant
}

//and in your HTML:

<form>
  <textarea id="theBox" rows="2" cols="60">Here's the string</textarea>
  <input type="button" value="get the string" onclick="getMyString()" /> 
</form>
```